# How to generate a png or jpg image from a Uint8Array array of rgb values with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js

I'm creating procedural planet textures for my space simulator, and the output that I end up with is a Uint8Array of RGB values, like so `[255, 255, 255, 100, 200, 50]`.

With three.js you can convert these values into a texture with the `THREE.DataTexture` class, but generating them in run time is rather slow if you want high-resolution textures, so I would like to produce the textures with node.js so that I can use them like I would any other texture.

Could anyone shed some light on how I could achieve the above? Ideally, I'd like the output to be either a jpg or png image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jpeg-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-js) is JavaScript JPEG encoder and decoder for `node.js`. This allows you to create JPG files from `Buffer` objects via `jpeg.encode()`. You can create the `Buffer` instance like so:

```js
const data = new Uint16Array(6);

arr[0] = 255;
arr[1] = 255;
arr[2] = 255;
arr[3] = 100;
arr[4] = 200;
arr[5] = 50;

const buffer = Buffer.from( data );
```